# How to pass 2 parameters to $http in angularjs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have Web api controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SetAt(int id,TableModel idModel)
{
    table[id] = idModel;
}
```

I try to access it with the aid of the method

```
$http.post("http://localhost:58652/api/Values/SetAt", data);
```

But I do not know how to pass data to the method $http.post works correctly.

Data:

- For `id =0;`
- For `idModel={ field: "Id", width: 200 };`

How to do it?

Comment: I think, you want to pass multiple object. then try 
 {{
  "field": "0",
  "width": 200,
  
 },
 {
  "field": "1",
  "width": 300,
  
 }
}

Comment: I want to pass something like { id:0,  idModel: { field: "Id", width: 200 }; }

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var data = {
        id: 0,
        idModel: {
            field: "id",
            width: 200
        }
    };

$http.post("http://localhost:58652/api/Values/SetAt", data);
```

Basically, the properties in your JavaScript object should match the parameters of your C# method.  So

- "id" will map to "int id" (with a value of 0), and
- "idModel" will map to "TableModel idModel" (with the properties "field" and "width" set to "id" and "200" respectively)

---

I have not worked with Web API Controllers much, you may have to pass the "id" in the route (depending on your setup), which would make your code look like this:

```
var id = 0,
    data = {
        field: "id",
        width: 200
    };

$http.post("http://localhost:58652/api/Values/SetAt/" + id, data);
```

Comment: this not work because "int id" takes "int" ,and pass object {"id":0}

Comment: with the post can not be transferred "?id=0"

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding your comments, @Denis.  Did you try the second solution I added to my answer?  I just updated it because I left out a "/" at the end of the URL.

Comment: @Denis So this solved your problem?  That's great!  I'm glad to hear it =)